# Join two Pandas DataFrames on specific column with matching values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to join two pandas dataframes on "ColA", but the thing is that values in "ColA" in these two dataframes are not in order and dataframes are not the same lenght. I want to join them so that missing values are changed with 0 value, and that values in "ColA" are matching.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ColA":["num 1", "num 2", "num 3"],
                   "ColB":[5,6,7]})

print(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ColA":["num 2", "num 3","num 1", "num 4"],
                   "ColC":[3,2,1,5]})

print(df2)


    ColA  ColB
0  num 1     5
1  num 2     6
2  num 3     7

    ColA  ColC
0  num 2     3
1  num 3     2
2  num 1     1
3  num 4     5
```

Result should look like this:

```
# num1 is matched with appropriate values and num4 has the value 0 for "ColB" 

    ColA  ColB  ColC
0  num 1     5     1
1  num 2     6     3
2  num 3     7     2
3  num 4     0     5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with outer join, convert `NaN`s to `0` and last if necessary convert `dtype`s to original by dictionary:

```
d = df1.dtypes.append(df2.dtypes).to_dict()
df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='ColA').fillna(0).astype(d)
print (df)

    ColA  ColB  ColC
0  num 1     5     1
1  num 2     6     3
2  num 3     7     2
3  num 4     0     5
```

Or use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with convert all columns to integers (if possible):

```
df = (pd.concat([df1.set_index('ColA'), 
                df2.set_index('ColA')], axis=1, sort=True)
        .fillna(0)
        .astype(int)
        .rename_axis('ColA')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
    ColA  ColB  ColC
0  num 1     5     1
1  num 2     6     3
2  num 3     7     2
3  num 4     0     5
```